# PyQt4 pass transformation matrix as argument to constructor

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am writing a widget for PyQt4 and the project style guide dictates that I pass static properties of Qt elements through kwargs in the constructor.

Unfortunately, I am having trouble finding the correct kwarg name for the property I want to pass.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.scene, self.mainArea)

# Flip y axis for sane drawing
matrix = QtGui.QMatrix()
matrix.scale(1, -1)
self.view.setMatrix(matrix)
```

I want to find a way to pass the `matrix` through the `QGraphicsView` constructor, if that's even possible.

I have tried the following

```
self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.scene, self.mainArea, matrix=matrix)
self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.scene, self.mainArea, transform=matrix)
```

but both of these instances tell me that they are unknown keyword arguments. I am not sure if this is even possible through the constructor, but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer anywhere.

I am also fuzzy on what the "static properties" of Qt elements are exactly.

Comment: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsview.html based on this docs I don't think so you can create a constructor with those arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you've understood the style guide properly? I doubt that it expects you to set *every possible property of every conceivable class* using kwargs. The `QGraphicsView` class has [eighty properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#properties). Do you think it's plausible that Qt would define constructors with *eighty* optional arguments?

I think it's more likely that the guide is simply asking you to use kwargs *wherever they are available*. Otherwise, you should just use the property setter functions.

PS:

The [matrix](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#matrix) of a `QGraphicsView` is not a property anyway, so for your specific example, the point is moot.

Comment: This is exactly my question. The style guide asked me to pass them as arguments when available, but I was unsure where I could find a list of arguments that could be passed. If it's not possible, this helps me just as much, since I wasn't sure if the appropriate constructor was defined. I would, however, like to know where you got the list of arguments from, since I have been unable to find a comprehensive documentation on PyQt4.

Comment: @Pavlin. I gave the relevant links to the qt docs in my answer. There's also a pyqt version of the qt docs [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html).